# How to use ScreenViewport properly with an AWT Canvas in LibGdx?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, libgdx, viewport

I'm making a Swing application using LibGdx as a backend for the map editor part. I use a `LwjglApplication` and pass a `java.awt.Canvas` to it.

I use a `ScreenViewport` to make the area being resize as the window is resized, but it does not work. The graphics is interpolated with a bad aspect ratio.

```
public class MapEditorCanvas extends JPanel implements ApplicationListener
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5383413314123855231L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private Canvas _canvas;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public MapEditorCanvas()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        _canvas = new Canvas();
        add(_canvas,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        LwjglApplication app = new LwjglApplication(this, _canvas);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private Sprite sprite;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private Viewport viewport;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private OrthographicCamera  _camera;


    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        _camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        _camera.setToOrtho(true);
        _camera.update();

        viewport = new ScreenViewport(_camera);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();  

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(_camera.combined);
        sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("project/assets/graphics/wheel.png")));

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        GL11.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
        batch.begin();
        viewport.apply();   
        sprite.draw(batch);     
        batch.end();    
    }

    //
    // Some others methods
    // 


    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override 
    public void resize(int width, int height){
        viewport.setScreenSize(width, height);
        viewport.update(width, height, false);
        _camera.setToOrtho(true,width,height);
        _camera.update();
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code ?

Bonus question : the LibGdx application is not drawn until the component is resized, someone knows why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into LwjglCanvas? It's built into libgdx and works pretty well. I've been using it lately for my own map editor. Btw, when you want to add it to your JPanel, use lwjglCanvas.getCanvas(), that will return an awt.Canvas you can use.

Comment: Nice ! And no more `Viewport` required ! Thank you. I just wonder why there are as many ways to do the same thing with a canvas in Lwjgl :)